# XPathSelectElements where the value contains a quaote

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Hi I have looked at several answers and none seems to work for my problem(or may be i did some thing wrong) I have the following xml and would like to select the elements in the This 'wont hurt Quiz.

This is the Code I tried

```
 xd = XDocument.Load(XmlFile);
 var node = xd.XPathSelectElements("/Math/Quiz[QuizTitle ='This 'wont hurt']");
```

It did not work because it says I have an invalid token I looked it up and found that it is the ' causing the problem but none of the escaping methods seem to work that I have found and Ideas or help would be grate spent a lot of time on this silly problem already before deciding to ask  question

**XML**

```
 <Math>
  <Quiz>
    <QuizTitle>This 'wont hurt</QuizTitle>
    <Questions>20</Questions>
    <Time>15/</Time>
  </Quiz>
    <Quiz>
    <QuizTitle>Test</QuizTitle>
    <Questions>1</Questions>
    <Time>14/</Time>
  </Quiz>
 </Math>
```

Comment: '/Math/Quiz[QuizTitle ="This \'wont hurt"]' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following `XPath`:

```
xd.XPathSelectElements("/Math/Quiz[QuizTitle=\"This 'wont hurt\"]")
```

The difference is, it's using `"` instead of `'` to set text content, and that's why you can use `'` within the text without any problems.

Returns what you need:

```xml
<Quiz>
  <QuizTitle>This 'wont hurt</QuizTitle>
  <Questions>20</Questions>
  <Time>15/</Time>
</Quiz>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked 100% now I will just have to look at making a function to take care of this for me ,or may be just a string builder might do.